# Bootstrap laravel from public sub-folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have a Laravel v5.5 running on apache and I need to implement user verification over smart card certificates (using apache SSLVerifyClient require).

This means that I need a public folder, that will ask for client's certificate and my public folder structure is following:

```
/public/
 |- index.php <-- laravel main bootstrap
 |- login/
    |- .htaccess <-- let's apache to ask for client cert only on this folder
    |- index.php <-- secondary bootstrap, that should work as main bootstrap
```

**How can I bootstrap laravel from sub-folder** (*public/login/index.php*)**, so that it will keep the paths and routing as in main bootstrap** (*public/index.php*)**?**

I've tried doing

```
<?php
require_once '../index.php';
```

and

```
<?php
// copy-paste the content from ../index.php and change the paths

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));
require __DIR__.'/../../vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../bootstrap/app.php';

// ...
```

But they both handle routes as though "**/login**" is the home root "**/**"

Comment: My god... /login should be going into `/resources/views/` not the public folder

Comment: no-no, /login doesn't output anything. It's just a directory, that will be used to invoke apache's "SSLVerifyClient = require" rule on. Then the client certificate, that is received from verification, will be used to log client in, for which I need bootstrapped laravel.

Comment: have you tried `public_path()/login/index.php` ?

Comment: Could you explain that a bit more? Afaik, public_path() is laravel's helper method and I can't access it when laravel is not bootstrapped (initiated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I have currently as a working solution. As the sole purpose for the separate /login path was to collect certificate info from $_SERVER and then pass it on to proper laravel controller, I only needed bootstrapped laravel to get access to correct session instance.

```
// -- file login/index.php

// bootstrap laravel
require __DIR__.'/../../vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../bootstrap/app.php';
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);
$request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture();

// trigger all the middlewares (including SessionStart)
$response = $kernel->handle($request);

// check client verification and store certificate information to session
$request->session()->put([
    'login-card-cert' => $request->server('SSL_CLIENT_CERT'),
    'login-card-user' => $request->server('SSL_CLIENT_S_DN'),
]);
$request->session()->save();

// use away() to send user out of the sub-folder and back to main laravel route
$response = redirect()->away('/do-login/');

// finish up with request (laravel termination)
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```